# Unable to unload content in XML gallery - AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, gallery

I have an XML gallery and I want in the **next** button function to "unload" **all content** and load new XML file.

So far I use this code:

```
  function navigateToRight(evt:MouseEvent):void{    

  if (thumbsHolder.numChildren > 0){    
  while (thumbsHolder.numChildren) {
        thumbsHolder.removeChildAt(0);          
    }       
    removeloaded();}

    loadXml("2.xml");   
  }
```

Where `removeloaded` function is `loader.unload();`

Unfortunately when i press next button I can see the new xml file is loaded but the items are from the previous xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Solution founded!

I had to **re-declare** the Array that holds my XML objects everytime I load a new XML file.